# Convert ffmpeg frame into array of YUV pixels in C

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I'm using the ffmpeg C libraries and trying to convert an AVFrame into a 2d array of pixels with YUV* components for analysis. I figured out how to convert the Y component for each pixel.:

```
uint8_t y_val = pFrame->data[0][pFrame->linesize[0] * y + x];
```

Since all frames have a Y component this is easy. However most digital video do not have a 4:4:4 chroma subsampling, so getting the UV components is stumping me.

I'm using straight C for this project. No C++. An ideas?

*Note: Yes, I know it's technically YCbCr and not YUV.

Edit:

I'm rather new to C so it might not be the prettiest code out there.

When I try:

```
VisYUVFrame *VisCreateYUVFrame(const AVFrame *pFrame){
    VisYUVFrame *tmp = (VisYUVFrame*)malloc(sizeof(VisYUVFrame));
    if(tmp == NULL){ return NULL;}
    tmp->height = pFrame->height;
    tmp->width = pFrame->width;

    tmp->data = (PixelYUV***)malloc(sizeof(PixelYUV**) * pFrame->height);
    if(tmp->data == NULL) { return NULL;};

    for(int y = 0; y < pFrame->height; y++){
        tmp->data[y] = (PixelYUV**)malloc(sizeof(PixelYUV*) * pFrame->width);
        if(tmp->data[y] == NULL) { return NULL;}

        for(int x = 0; x < pFrame->width; x++){
            tmp->data[y][x] = (PixelYUV*)malloc(sizeof(PixelYUV*));
            if(tmp->data[y][x] == NULL){ return NULL;};
            tmp->data[y][x]->Y = pFrame->data[0][pFrame->linesize[0] * y + x];
            tmp->data[y][x]->U = pFrame->data[1][pFrame->linesize[1] * y + x];
            tmp->data[y][x]->V = pFrame->data[2][pFrame->linesize[2] * y + x];

        }
    }

    return tmp;
```

Luma works but when I run Valgrind, I get

> 0x26
>    1
>     InvalidRead
>     Invalid read of size 1
>     
>       
>         0x100003699
>         /Users/hborcher/Library/Caches/CLion2016.2/cmake/generated/borcherscope-8e83e7dd/8e83e7dd/Debug/VisCreator2
>         VisCreateYUVFrame
>         /Users/hborcher/ClionProjects/borcherscope/lib
>         visualization.c
>         145
>       
>       
>         0x100006B5B
>         /Users/hborcher/Library/Caches/CLion2016.2/cmake/generated/borcherscope-8e83e7dd/8e83e7dd/Debug/VisCreator2
>         render
>         /Users/hborcher/ClionProjects/borcherscope/lib/decoder
>         simpleDecoder2.c
>         253
>       
>       
>         0x100002D24
>         /Users/hborcher/Library/Caches/CLion2016.2/cmake/generated/borcherscope-8e83e7dd/8e83e7dd/Debug/VisCreator2
>         main
>         /Users/hborcher/ClionProjects/borcherscope/src
>         createvisual2.c
>         93
>       
>     
>     Address 0x10e9f91ef is 0 bytes after a block of size 92,207 alloc'd
>     
>       
>         0x100013EEA
>         /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.11.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so
>         malloc_zone_memalign
>       
>       
>         0x1084B5416
>         /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
>         posix_memalign
>       
>       
>         0x10135D317
>         /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.2/lib/libavutil.55.17.103.dylib
>         av_malloc
>
> 0x27
>     1
>     InvalidRead
>     Invalid read of size 1
>     
>       
>         0x1000036BA
>         /Users/hborcher/Library/Caches/CLion2016.2/cmake/generated/borcherscope-8e83e7dd/8e83e7dd/Debug/VisCreator2
>         VisCreateYUVFrame
>         /Users/hborcher/ClionProjects/borcherscope/lib
>         visualization.c
>         147
>       
>       
>         0x100006B5B
>         /Users/hborcher/Library/Caches/CLion2016.2/cmake/generated/borcherscope-8e83e7dd/8e83e7dd/Debug/VisCreator2
>         render
>         /Users/hborcher/ClionProjects/borcherscope/lib/decoder
>         simpleDecoder2.c
>         253
>       
>       
>         0x100002D24
>         /Users/hborcher/Library/Caches/CLion2016.2/cmake/generated/borcherscope-8e83e7dd/8e83e7dd/Debug/VisCreator2
>         main
>         /Users/hborcher/ClionProjects/borcherscope/src
>         createvisual2.c
>         93
>       
>     
>     Address 0x10e9f91ef is 0 bytes after a block of size 92,207 alloc'd
>     
>       
>         0x100013EEA
>         /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.11.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so
>         malloc_zone_memalign
>       
>       
>         0x1084B5416
>         /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
>         posix_memalign
>       
>       
>         0x10135D317
>         /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.2/lib/libavutil.55.17.103.dylib
>         av_malloc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with hardcoding the chroma subsampling, e.g. you know the frame data format is 4:2:0, it's simple:

```
int uvy = y >> 1, uvx = x >> 1;
uint8_t u_val = pFrame->data[1][pFrame->linesize[1] * uvy + uvx];
uint8_t v_val = pFrame->data[2][pFrame->linesize[2] * uvy + uvx];
```

If you want it to be more generic, use this:

```
AVPixFmtDescriptor *desc = av_pix_fmt_desc_get(pFrame->format);
int uvy = y >> desc->log2_chroma_h, uvx = x >> desc->log2_chroma_w;
uint8_t u_val = pFrame->data[1][pFrame->linesize[1] * uvy + uvx];
uint8_t v_val = pFrame->data[2][pFrame->linesize[2] * uvy + uvx];
```

That should work for all cases to get pixels at any x,y location. However, don't use this to convert buffers of any chroma subsampling into 4:4:4 arrays, it will have visual artifacts. For display on-screen, use the original data and use per-plane sizing in e.g. your openGL shaders to convert the original arrays on-screen to the desired target resolution. To convert to 4:4:4 for other use cases, use [libswscale](https://www.ffmpeg.org/libswscale.html).

Comment: I actually tried the first  one when trying to solve this but when I ran Valgrind on my program, I got invalid read errors. I figured that converting to 4:4:4 might be my only option. I do want it to handle all chroma subsampling sources but everything should be YUV colorspace.

Comment: can you show the code that valgrind complained about, along with the actual valgrind warnings?

Comment: Ronald, see my edit. Any help would be great! I'm still getting feel for coding in straight C.

Comment: I don't see how your code and my first fragment are identical, yours uses x/y in data[1]/[2], whereas mine uses uvx/uvy, which is x>>1 and y>>1. So yes, yours overreads and causes valgrind errors, whereas mine is fine.

Comment: I'll take another look and get back to you.

Comment: oh I see the differences now. I'm new to c and this is the first time I've had a reason to use the binary shift operator.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh I see, sorry about that. So, x >> y is the same as x / (1 << y) which is roughly the same as x / pow(2, y). So x >> 1 is just x / 2. Sorry about that.